# Aggregating JSON values in Python

Tags: python, sql, json, database, file

I was wondering whether it was possible to aggregate JSON data into new values in python.

For example a single JSON value looks like this:

```
{"time": {"Friday": {"20:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 10, "21:00": 5, 
          "23:00": 14, "0:00": 2, "18:00": 2}, "Thursday": {"23:00": 1, 
          "0:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "18:00": 1, "16:00": 2, "22:00": 2},
          "Wednesday": {"17:00": 2, "23:00": 3, "16:00": 1, "22:00": 1, 
          "19:00": 1, "21:00": 1}, "Sunday": {"16:00": 2, "17:00": 2, "19:00": 1, 
          "22:00": 4, "21:00": 4, "0:00": 3, "1:00": 2}, "Saturday": 
          {"21:00": 4, "20:00": 3, "23:00": 10, "22:00": 7, "18:00": 
          1, "15:00": 2, "16:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "0:00": 8, "1:00": 
          1}, "Tuesday": {"19:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "1:00": 2, "21:00": 
          1, "23:00": 3}, "Monday": {"18:00": 2, "23:00": 1, "22:00": 2}}
```

I want to aggregate it such that it is in four categories based on the times it is open.

The four categories are:

6am - 12 noon : morning

12 noon - 5 pm: afternoon

5 pm - 11 pm: evening

11 pm - 6 am: night

For example:

If this is the current value:

```
“Friday”:{“20:00”: 5,“21:00”: 10}
```

Then the output should be:

```
"Friday": {"morning": 0, "afternoon": 0, "evening": 15, "night": 0}
```

Thus the output should be in the form

```
"Day": {"morning": count, "afternoon": count, "evening": count, "night":count}
```

For all of the hundreds of JSON values.

My thinking was that I could create 4 bins representing each of the time zones. I would then use two for loops to go through each days values. If the value is in the range of the bucket I would add it to the count. I would then store the day in a dictionary with the values being a dictionary as well. The inner dictionary would consist of the four time zones with the count as the value. I would then return this for the day and restart for each day.

Here's what I have so far, still need to implement the aggregate function.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

def cleanStr4SQL(s):
    return s.replace("'","`").replace("\n"," ")

def parseCheckinData():
    #write code to parse yelp_checkin.JSON
    with open('yelp_checkin.JSON') as f:
        outfile = open('checkin.txt', 'w')
        line = f.readline()
        count_line = 0
        while line:
            data = json.loads(line)
            outfile.write(cleanStr4SQL(str(data['business_id'])) + '\t')
            outfile.write(aggregate(cleanStr4SQL(str(data['time']))))

            line = f.readline()
            count_line+=1
    print(count_line)
    outfile.close()
    f.close()

def aggregate(line):
    morning = []
    afternoon = []
    evening = []
    night = []
    for l in line:
        print(l)
```

I was wondering what the best approach to solving this in python would be.

Any advice is appreciated. I know there is no code, but if someone could point me in a direction that would be great.

Thank you for reading

Comment: You are dealing with a time series type of data. Try looking for an specific package to handle that. As an example, mongodb has native methods to handle data aggregation.

Comment: Interesting I'll look into it. Also just wondering but do you know what the best way to iterate through this JSON value would be? Thanks!

Comment: At first glance I would iterate day by day and create the new categories (morning, evening, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way to approach it. I tried it with just one json string so  you may have to extend it to handle multiple occurrences.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

jsontxt = '{"time": {"Friday": {"20:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 10, "21:00": 5, "23:00": 14, "0:00": 2, "18:00": 2}, "Thursday": {"23:00": 1, "0:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "18:00": 1, "16:00": 2, "22:00": 2}, "Wednesday": {"17:00": 2, "23:00": 3, "16:00": 1, "22:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "21:00": 1}, "Sunday": {"16:00": 2, "17:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 4, "21:00": 4, "0:00": 3, "1:00": 2}, "Saturday": {"21:00": 4, "20:00": 3, "23:00": 10, "22:00": 7, "18:00": 1, "15:00": 2, "16:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "0:00": 8, "1:00": 1}, "Tuesday": {"19:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "1:00": 2, "21:00": 1, "23:00": 3}, "Monday": {"18:00": 2, "23:00": 1, "22:00": 2}}}'

# Parse the json and convert to a dictionary object
jsondict = json.loads(jsontxt)

# Convert the "time" element in the dictionary to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(jsondict['time'])

# Define a function to convert the time slots to the categories
def cat(time_slot):
    if '06:00' <= time_slot < '12:00':
        return 'Morning'
    elif '12:00' <= time_slot < '17:00':
        return 'Afternoon'
    elif '17:00' <= time_slot < '23:00':
        return 'Evening'
    else:
        return 'Night'

# Add a new column "Time" to the DataFrame and set the values after left padding the values in the index
df['Time'] = df.index.str.rjust(5,'0')

# Add a new column "Category" and the set the values based on the time slot
df['Category'] = df['Time'].apply(cat)

# Create a pivot table based on the "Category" column
pt = df.pivot_table(index='Category', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

# Convert the pivot table to a dictionary to get the json output you want
jsonoutput = pt.to_dict()
print(jsonoutput)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Amazingly brilliant! it didn't occur to me to use the pandas library. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the words of appreciation. Glad to be of help.